# 0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'cookie'

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I am developing mvc web application. I have added following scripts in bundle

```
 bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/adminscripts").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.js",
                    "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.dcjqaccordion.2.7.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.scrollTo.min.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.nicescroll.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.sparkline.js",
                    "~/Scripts/assets/jquery-easy-pie-chart/jquery.easy-pie-chart.js",
                    "~/Scripts/owl.carousel.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.customSelect.js",
                    "~/Scripts/respond.js",
                    "~/Scripts/slidebars.js",
                    "~/Scripts/common-scripts.js",
                    "~/Scripts/sparkline-chart.js",
                    "~/Scripts/easy-pie-chart.js",
                    "~/Scripts/count.js",
                    "~/Scripts/Main.js"));
```

When I run the site it is giving me this error

> 0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'cookie'

Instead of adding these scripts in bundle if I add it on my `_LayOut.cshtml` then all works fine. I have added `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;` in my `Bundle.config`. I am not getting where is the issue. Can someone help me to solve this? I searched that `cookie` keyword entire from my solution and I didn't find anything. Please see following screenshot

[image]

I have upgraded my scripts by using nugget command line package manager. But still my problem isn't solved. I found the script which cause an issue.

### EDIT

**~/Scripts/common-scripts.js** this script giving me error.

Here is script code

```
/*---LEFT BAR ACCORDION----*/
$(function () {
    $('#nav-accordion').dcAccordion({
        eventType: 'click',
        autoClose: true,
        saveState: true,
        disableLink: true,
        speed: 'slow',
        showCount: false,
        autoExpand: true,
        //        cookie: 'dcjq-accordion-1',
        classExpand: 'dcjq-current-parent'
    });
});

// right slidebar
$(function () {
    $.slidebars();
});

var Script = function () {

    //    sidebar dropdown menu auto scrolling
    jQuery('#sidebar .sub-menu > a').click(function () {
        var o = ($(this).offset());
        diff = 250 - o.top;
        if (diff > 0)
            $("#sidebar").scrollTo("-=" + Math.abs(diff), 500);
        else
            $("#sidebar").scrollTo("+=" + Math.abs(diff), 500);
    });

    //    sidebar toggle
    $(function () {
        function responsiveView() {
            var wSize = $(window).width();
            if (wSize <= 768) {
                $('#container').addClass('sidebar-close');
                $('#sidebar > ul').hide();
            }

            if (wSize > 768) {
                $('#container').removeClass('sidebar-close');
                $('#sidebar > ul').show();
            }
        }
        $(window).on('load', responsiveView);
        $(window).on('resize', responsiveView);
    });

    $('.fa-bars').click(function () {
        if ($('#sidebar > ul').is(":visible") === true) {
            $('#main-content').css({
                'margin-left': '0px'
            });
            $('#sidebar').css({
                'margin-left': '-210px'
            });
            $('#sidebar > ul').hide();
            $("#container").addClass("sidebar-closed");
        } else {
            $('#main-content').css({
                'margin-left': '210px'
            });
            $('#sidebar > ul').show();
            $('#sidebar').css({
                'margin-left': '0'
            });
            $("#container").removeClass("sidebar-closed");
        }
    });

    // custom scrollbar
    $("#sidebar").niceScroll({ styler: "fb", cursorcolor: "#e8403f", cursorwidth: '3', cursorborderradius: '10px', background: '#404040', spacebarenabled: false, cursorborder: '' });

    $("html").niceScroll({ styler: "fb", cursorcolor: "#e8403f", cursorwidth: '6', cursorborderradius: '10px', background: '#404040', spacebarenabled: false, cursorborder: '', zindex: '1000' });

    // widget tools
    jQuery('.panel .tools .fa-chevron-down').click(function () {
        var el = jQuery(this).parents(".panel").children(".panel-body");
        if (jQuery(this).hasClass("fa-chevron-down")) {
            jQuery(this).removeClass("fa-chevron-down").addClass("fa-chevron-up");
            el.slideUp(200);
        } else {
            jQuery(this).removeClass("fa-chevron-up").addClass("fa-chevron-down");
            el.slideDown(200);
        }
    });

    // by default collapse widget
    //    $('.panel .tools .fa').click(function () {
    //        var el = $(this).parents(".panel").children(".panel-body");
    //        if ($(this).hasClass("fa-chevron-down")) {
    //            $(this).removeClass("fa-chevron-down").addClass("fa-chevron-up");
    //            el.slideUp(200);
    //        } else {
    //            $(this).removeClass("fa-chevron-up").addClass("fa-chevron-down");
    //            el.slideDown(200); }
    //    });

    jQuery('.panel .tools .fa-times').click(function () {
        jQuery(this).parents(".panel").parent().remove();
    });

    //    tool tips
    $('.tooltips').tooltip();

    //    popovers
    $('.popovers').popover();

    // custom bar chart
    if ($(".custom-bar-chart")) {
        $(".bar").each(function () {
            var i = $(this).find(".value").html();
            $(this).find(".value").html("");
            $(this).find(".value").animate({
                height: i
            }, 2000)
        })
    }
}();
```

Comment: My guess is that the scripts are getting minified during the bundling process and minified variables are overwriting each other.

Comment: @MikeLoffland Thank you for reply. Burt I removed `.min` from scripts.

Comment: @MikeLoffland I searched that `cookie` keyword entire from my solution and I didn't find anything.

Comment: If you set BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false and you don't get the error... It proves that minification is the cause.

Comment: Scripts/jquery.scrollTo.min.js

Comment: @MikeLoffland I renamed `jquery.scrollTo.min.js` to `jquery.scrollTo.js` still same issue.

Comment: You can't just rename it... You have to include the non-minified version instead.

Comment: Are you sure it's "working fine"? You may have just moved the problem into the browser. Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: @TiesonT. Yes. If I add these scripts on _Layout.js then It's working fine no any error. but when I add these to bundle then it is giving error

Comment: @AjayPunekar Have you tried removing all of the libraries from your bundle, and then adding & compiling them one-by-one? I'm assuming you're getting a conflict somewhere, given how many scripts you're trying to bundle together.

Comment: right now I am trying this. Let's check which script giving an issue

Comment: @TiesonT. I found the cause `common-scripts.js`. When I add this script in bundle it is giving me an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source of that dcjqAccordian, it tries to call `$.cookie` to save it's state. You'll need to add jQuery.Cookie as a script for that to work: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie or https://www.nuget.org/packages/jquery.cookie/

So, your bundle will look something like:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/adminscripts").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.cookie.*",
                    "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.dcjqaccordion.2.7.js",
                    ... etc.
```

As an aside, I would avoid using a plain "jquery.js" reference; assuming you're using the NuGet package, you would normally use:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/adminscripts").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.cookie.*",
                    "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.dcjqaccordion.2.7.js",
                    ... etc.
```

Comment: thanks for reply. I have added this script to my solution. Right now it is giving me error in `slidebars`.

Comment: It's working now. My mistake. I entered wrong path to `slidebars.js` file